# Stripe Subscription Upgrade Causing Unwanted Invoice Item

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to upgrade my user's package via Stripe API, from "59$ per month" package to "109$ per month" package and **immediately** charge (109-59=50$) / invoice the user. This is how I am doing:

```
const subscription: Stripe.Subscription = await this.stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
            EXISTING SUBSCRIPTION ID,
        );
await this.stripe.subscriptions.update(EXISTING SUBSCRIPTION ID, {
        cancel_at_period_end: false,
        proration_behavior: 'create_prorations',
        items: [{
            id: subscription.items.data[0].id,
            price: PRICE ID OF NEW PACKAGE,
        }]
    });
```

This is upgrading my user's package successfully but the invoice looks like this:

[image]

The part "JAN 28 - FEB 28" is correct. It's subtotal is 50$ that is correct. But why it's also automatically subscribing for the next period (FED 28 - MAR 28). This shouldn't be in the invoice. And the invoice total should be 50$ not 159$.

Answer (score 0):

Prorations default to being on the next period's Invoice. You need to set `proration_behavior` to `always_invoice` in order to immediately create an Invoice for the current prorations. ([documented here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior))